# Absolute path in RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My link which need to be rewrited :

> http://www.example.com/uploads/lu/full/00bcde2d484f1dab979c19f14b2f38bfabf13496_152_152.jpg

My rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://test.mywebsite.com/themes/publisher/vignettes/resize.php?src=$1.$4&h=$2&w=$3
```

Output url

> http://test.mywebsite.com/themes/publisher/vignettes/resize.php?src=uploads/lu/full/00bcde2d484f1dab979c19f14b2f38bfabf13496.jpg&h=152&w=152

Expected url

> http://test.mywebsite.com/themes/publisher/vignettes/resize.php?src=http://www.example.com/uploads/lu/full/00bcde2d484f1dab979c19f14b2f38bfabf13496.jpg&h=152&w=152

http://www.example.com is not on my output url and i don't understand why

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture values from `%{REQUEST_URI` that always contains full path:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/([^/]*?)_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://test.mywebsite.com/themes/publisher/vignettes/resize.php?src=http://%{HTTP_HOST}%1/%2.%5&h=%3&w=%4 [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: It works on htaccess tester like [htaccess.mwl.be/](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) output url is correct, but not on my server

Comment: You need to provide more details about the problem you're facing on your server like what URL did you use for testing and what it gets redirected to? Also make sure this is very first rule.

Comment: Request url : http://sortiraujourdhui.fr/uploads/lu/full/00bcde2d484f1dab979c19f14b2f38bfabf13496_152_152.jpg - output url : http://test.sortiraujourdhui.fr/themes/publisher/vignettes/resize.php?src=http://sortiraujourdhui.fr/uploads/lu/full/00bcde2d484f1dab979c19f14b2f38bfabf13496.jpg&h=152&w=152 - This is the only rule

Comment: And how it is not working because as per question above: `http://test.sortiraujourdhui.fr/themes/publisher/vignettes/resize.php?src=http://sortiraujourdhui.fr/uploads/lu/full/00bcde2d484f1dab979c19f14b2f38bfabf13496.jpg&h=152&w=152` is your **Expected url**

Comment: I don't understand your last comment, http://test.sortiraujourdhui.fr/themes/publisher/vignettes/resize.php?src=http​//sortiraujourdhui.fr/uploads/lu/full/00bcde2d484f1dab979c19f14b2f38bfabf13496.jp‌​g&h=152&w=152 is my expected url which is redirected from http://www.sortiraujourdhui.fr/uploads/lu/full/00bcde2d484f1dab979c19f14b2f38bfabf13496_152_152.jpg

Comment: I don't see help link you tell

Comment: Just wrap your URLs or code in reverse quotes `\`` which is on left hand side of `1` on your keyboard. See my comment where I've used same for URL posted in previous comment

Comment: Request url : `http://www.sortiraujourdhui.fr/uploads/lu/full/00bcde2d484f1dab979c19f14b2f38bfabf13496_152_152.jpg`
 - Expected url : `http://test.sortiraujourdhui.fr/themes/publisher/vignettes/resize.php?src=http://sortiraujourdhui.fr/uploads/lu/full/00bcde2d484f1dab979c19f14b2f38bfabf13496.jpg&h=152&w=152`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110421/discussion-between-anubhava-and-bklups).